# What is Windows Azure Storage Analytics?

Tags: azure, analytics, azure-storage

Someone explain to me what it is and how the Windows Azure Storage Analytics works and how I can use it in conjunction with storage.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/08/03/announcing-windows-azure-storage-analytics.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Azure Storage Analytics offers [profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29) like capabilities for Azure Storage (which includes Tables, Blobs and Queues).

You can find a very good overview of Azure Storage Analytics directly on [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/08/03/announcing-windows-azure-storage-analytics.aspx). Then, for digging deeper and also getting some code samples, you can go [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/08/03/windows-azure-storage-logging-using-logs-to-track-storage-requests.aspx) related to the logging functionality and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/08/03/windows-azure-storage-metrics-using-metrics-to-track-storage-usage.aspx) for the metrics one.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the new Windows Azure Storage Analytics App for Windows 8 in the app store:

[image: Azure Storage Monitor]

http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-US/app/azure-storage-monitor/e9292e05-c469-403d-a787-63645b861593